# A good way to redirect with a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, django, redirect

I need to redirect a user to an external site though a POST request.

The only option I figured out is to do it submit a form through JavaScript.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? You want to send/forward the POST data to another server? You want the users browser to redirect after she POSTed a request? Something else...?

Answer (score 89):

It's not quite clear what you mean, so let's take a few scenarios:

1. **User should POST form to a server other than your own**

   Easy, just specify the target as the form action:

   ```
    <form action="http://someotherserver.com" method="post">
   ```
2. **User should be redirected after a successful POST submit**

   Easy, accept and process the POST data as usual, then respond with a `302` or `303` redirect header.
3. **User should POST data to your server and, after validation, you want to POST that data to another server**

   Slightly tricky, but three options:

   - Your server accepts the POST data and while the user waits for a response, you establish a connection to another server, POSTing the data, receiving a response, then return an answer to the user.
   - You answer with a **`307`** redirect, which means the user should attempt the same request at another address. Theoretically it means the browser should POST the same data to another server. I'm not quite sure how well supported this is, but any browser understanding HTTP1.1 should be able to do it. AFAIA it's not used that often in practice.
     **PS:** The specification says that a 307 POST redirect needs to be at least acknowledged by the user. Alas, apparently no browser is sticking to the spec here. IE simply repeats the request (so it works for your purposes), but Firefox, Safari and Opera seem to discard the POST data. Hence, this technique is unfortunately unreliable.
   - Use technique #1 combined with hidden form fields, adding one step in between.

See here for a list of all HTTP redirection options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Comment: I happen to know that 307 Redirects on FF19 will cause the Confirmation Dialog to come up. Not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: Sir, it is possible for the server to redirect the incoming GET request, to POST request? The details  are as follows: (1) A user clicks a hyperlink (`News` for example), (2) The server redirects the incoming GET request by sending a response (to the user) that will send POST request to the server. It forces the user to send POST request right after clicking the hyperlink.

Comment: @TheShortestMustacheTheorem No.

Comment: First: This is a great answer.  Lots of people who land on this page (like me!) want to know all the possibilities.  In my experience, `302` and `303` in a web browser will induce an HTTP GET request.  I use this to convert an incoming POST reply from an SSO authentication service, to then redirect to a final URL via HTTP GET.

Answer (score 7):

Just set HTML form's action URL to the particular external site.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2604530</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604530/answer/submit" method="post">
            <textarea name="post-text"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post Your Answer">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*You'll see that Stackoverflow has good CSRF protection ;)*

Answer (score 6):

Javascript is the only way (to do it automatically). You simply can't redirect a `POST` request via standard `http` methods. Are you sure that `GET` isn't an option here?

Answer (score 1):

Using a form is probably your only option as links, HTTP redirects and `<meta http-equiv="refresh" >` will only cause the browser to load another URL using the *GET* method.

You don't necessarily have to use JavaScript to submit a form though. If some user interaction is acceptable you could use a form with some `<input type="hidden">` fields and let the user press the submit button.

You may also want to ensure that the page you're redirecting to doesn't already accept GET parameters. *Some scripts* accept both GET and POST indiscriminately.