# Return HttpResponseMessage with a URL and post parameter

Tags: redirect, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, httpresponsemessage

I have a WebAPI request made from my UI to WebAPI. This needs to return an HttpResponseMessage with a status code of HttpStatusCode.Moved, so that browser is redirected to another URL. My problem is that this target URL has to be a POST request, with a POST parameter. How do i accomplish this?
So far i have tried:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
var json = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "postparameter", postparameter } };
response.Content = new StringContent(json.ToString());
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(targetURL);
return response;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604530/a-good-way-to-redirect-with-a-post-request

Comment: I want to do this without involving the UI. Redirection should happen from the WebAPI itself.

Comment: Is this possible? any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I did not understand.....could you please elaborate?

Comment: If the UI make a post to your api on "http://yourapi.com/user" and if you make a new post from the web api, C# code, and then return that response to the UI. The UI will only know the original url  "http://yourapi.com/user"

Comment: Figured out a solution already. It is something similar to what you have said above, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @user5663970 Can you share with us your solution?