# Yii2 how to send form request to external url

Tags: php, post, yii2

How to send a redirect post request to external url? my code in controller:

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
      // send post request to external link
    }
```

Comment: The answer is: you can't. You can save variables in session or build html form and autosubmit it by JavaScript.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: @AntonRybalko Hi, because I want to redirect to a hosted page(which is an external link) and it requires a parameters to be sent via http post request form redirect.

Comment: I can't use curl on this one since it needs to be redirected.

Comment: You can post data with curl and after the successful response, you can redirect it to external Url.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect your request using HTTP 301

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect('url', 301);
Yii::$app->end();
```

Or use any php http clients like Guzzle (see [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)).

There is no other options.

Comment: 301 redirection will loose POST data - you definitely don't want to do this.

Comment: You can send post data as get parameters. Or send post request via php http client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604530/a-good-way-to-redirect-with-a-post-request

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`307`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) status code to specify redirection which should be performed with the same POST data.

```
$this->redirect('https://example.com', 307);
```

> The `HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the `Location`headers.
>
> The method and the body of the original request are reused to perform the redirected request.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for this one. I can send my post request and gets redirected however the server isn't acknowledging my request, but when I use regular html form(not in yii2), it accepts my request. any thoughts on this? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can do it with [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). From [the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests) I think something like the below code is exactly what you want.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
        'form_params' => [
            'field_name' => 'abc',
            'other_field' => '123',
            'nested_field' => [
                'nested' => 'hello'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to the external server using CURL.

You can use the following code to send the post request to URL.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $url = 'http://www.example-redirect.com';
        $host = "http://www.example.com";
        $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();

        $ch = curl_init($host);
        $data = http_build_query($postData);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // Redirect from here
        return $this->redirect(Url::to($url));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks man, but it needs to be redirected to a hosted page.

Comment: For Redirection, you can use Url Helper.

`return $this->redirect(Url::to('https://www.example.com'));`