# How to redirect to a route from an external function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my component that represents the Login page

```
import { HttpService } from 'src/assets/js/httpservice';
// ** omissis other imports **

export default class PrivatePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <InputText name="Text" id="Text" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <InputText name="Email" id="Email" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Button onClick={this.send} label="Send ticket" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    private send() {
        HttpService.post(PATH.sendTicket, this.state.ticketModel).then(data => {
            if (data.ErrorCode === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    sentSuccessfull: true
                });
            }
            else {
                // show an error popup
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the "Send ticket" button is pressed, it calls the `HttpService.post` method to make an API call to send a ticket to the system. As you can see in the import section, the HttpService is hosted on an external JS file. This is the code of the `HttpService.post` method.

```
public static async post(path, body) {

    return window.fetch(path, {
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        cache: "no-cache",
        method: "post"
    })
        .then(data => {
            // call successfull
        })
        .catch(data => {
            if (data.status === 401) {
                // REDIRECT HERE
            }
            else {
                return data.json();
            }
        });
}
```

Now, if the API call fails because the user is not authenticated (HTTP status 401 is returned), I need to redirect the user to the Login page. I would avoid to handle the 401 HTTP status in every component, so I prefer that the redirect is made directly inside the `HttpService.post` method.

Comment: Is it duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604530/a-good-way-to-redirect-with-a-post-request?

Comment: No, the question in the linked post is completely different from my question.

Comment: is there a reason why you wont redirect on the client side in the private send functions else block? where you would be showing an error popup. You could have a close button on the error popup that fired a redirect for example.

Comment: @Lloyd I prefer that the redirect is made programmatically without any user interaction.

Comment: well you can still redirect programmatically on the client side, if you throw an error inside your catch block server side, then add a catch block client side with redirect. Before i answer just wanted to make sure if there was some other reason you didn't want it on the client side, as the end result is the same

Answer (score 0):

try the below and let me know if it works for you, change the server side like so:

```
public static async post(path, body) {

    return window.fetch(path, {
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        cache: "no-cache",
        method: "post"
        })
        .then(data => {
            // call successfull
        })
        .catch(data => {
            // server side redirect below:
            if (data.status === 401) {
              data.redirect(url, 401)
            }
            else {
            return data.json();
            }
        });
}
```

And then client side do the following:

```
     private send() {
     const { history } = this.props 
        HttpService.post(PATH.sendTicket, this.state.ticketModel).then(data => {
            if (data.ErrorCode === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    sentSuccessfull: true
                });
            }
        }).catch(err => {
          hirstory.push('/your-route-here')
        })
      }
```

Alternatively if you are not using react-router, instead of using history.push you can use

```
location.href = '/your-route-here'
```

Or something to that effect, however using location.href method will clear your app state, effectively behaving as if you refreshed the page.

Let me know if this helps

Lloyd

Comment: I've thought your same solution as a possible solution but if I put it in practice it would mean that I have to handle the 401 HTTP status in every React component doing a redirect. I would instead handle the 401 status globally only one time directly in the `post` method in the httpservice.js file.

Comment: ok i will edit with server side solution above, see the catch block in the server side promise.