# How can I send a POST request through header() with PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I need to use the header function in PHP to open a url, and in the process send some POST data to that site. For example, I'm using: `header("Location: creatordashboard.php");`. How can I send data to that URL once it redirects? I don't want to use GET, specifically POST.

Comment: See the third option here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604893/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas I need it in PHP, so this doesn't really work for me.

Comment: The link above is about HTTP status code.  You may use reference [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). To accept request from POST and redirect with POST, you have 2 options: 307, 308.

Comment: Do you want to use POST in order to hide the data from appearing in the URL? Anyway you might find something useful in the hack mentioned here: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-do-redirect-in-php-with-post-and-not-get/4968/5

Comment: Use [SESSION](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)  for this

Comment: POST data is transported in the request _body_. You can't set that by manipulating the request _headers_.

Comment: @JakeStBu - Did the answer work for you

Answer (score 1):

To use **POST** you have to submit a form.  You need to use the form tags and have a **button** or **input type=button**.

If you want to use the **header** then you have to either pass params and use **GET** or use the **SESSION** to pass information.

If you don't want to use a **form** and you don't like the **GET** then use the **SESSION**.